# Passing parameters to a custom getter in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have been reading about [properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html) in Kotlin, including custom getters and setters.

However, I was wondering if it is possible to create a custom getter with extra parameters.

For example, consider the following method in Java:

```
public String getDisplayedValue(Context context) {
    if (PrefUtils.useImperialUnits(context)) {
        // return stuff
    } else {
        // return other stuff
    }
}
```

*Note that the static method in `PrefUtils` has to have `Context` as a parameter, so removing this is not an option.*

I would like to write it like this in Kotlin:

```
val displayedValue: String
    get(context: Context) {
        return if (PrefUtils.useImperialUnits(context)) {
            // stuff
        } else {
            // other stuff
        }
    }
```

But my IDE highlights all of this in red.

I am aware I can create a function in my class to get the displayed value, but this would mean I would have to use `.getDisplayedValue(Context)` in Kotlin as well instead of being able to refer to the property by name as in `.displayedValue`.

Is there a way to create a custom getter like this?

EDIT: If not, would it be best to write a function for this, or to pass `Context` into the parameters of the class constructor?

Comment: Exactly same scenario! this is a small world, thanks for asking first :P

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As far as I know, property getter cannot have parameter. Write a function instead.

Comment: Would it be bad practice to pass `Context` into the parameters of the class constructor to use for the custom getter?

Comment: It is not the easiest way, but if you need the syntax of a property, then do it

Comment: There is a way to do this, using an intermediate object. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by having a property that returns an intermediate object that has a get and/or set operator with the parameters that you want, rather than returning the value directly.

Having that intermediate object be an inner class instance may be useful for providing easy access to the parent object. However, in an interface you can't use inner classes so in that case you might need to provide an explicit constructor parameter referencing the parent object when constructing your intermediate object.

For instance:

```
class MyClass {
    inner class Foo {
        operator fun get(context: Context): String {
            return if (PrefUtils.useImperialUnits(context)) {
                // return stuff
            } else {
                // return other stuff
            }
        }
    }
    val displayedValue = Foo()
}

...
val context : Context = whatever
val mc : MyClass = whatever
val y: String = mc.displayedValue[context]
```

However, if I knew that a specific context had a lifetime longer than that of any MyClass instance that depended on it, and that a specific context was always going to have to be passed into the properties of a specific MyClass instance, I would probably seriously consider just associating the MyClass instance with that context in its constructor, so that I didn't need to pass the context in to the getters and setters (and other functions?) each time it was needed. This would also guard against mistakes (what if the wrong context gets passed in?).

Answer (score -3):

You can do for example:

```
val displayedValue: String by lazy {
     val newString = context.getString(R.string.someString)
     newString
}
```

Comment: in your example that property MUST be placed somewhere where there is a context, however his example (the java method) is NOT context dependent as is passed as parameter.

Comment: why do u assign it first to newString?
you can directly call context.getString